# Swift Protocol How to declare as Generic conformance

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

Hello I have a problem with Swift Protocol

I have declared a protocol named BaseViewModel

I have class called AViewModel and BViewModel which conform to protocol BaseViewModel

```
class AViewModel : NSObject , BaseViewModel 

class BViewModel : NSObject , BaseViewModel
```

Now , I need to declare a completion block that returning those Object which conform to protocol BaseViewModel

```
typealias ViewModelCompletionBlock = (_ value : BaseViewModel) -> Void
```

In objective-C I used to declare something like this

```
id<BaseViewModel>
```

In Swift, how to declare the same ??

Comment: What is the problem with your `typealias ViewModelCompletionBlock = (_ value : BaseViewModel) -> Void` ? That already looks correct.

Comment: Can you make as best if my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
typealias ViewModelCompletionBlock<T: BaseViewModel> = (_ value : T) -> Void
```